# Fragment FrameLayout Animations when GONE

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-framelayout

Does anyone know or can give an example how this [fragment animation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=knF7RGqk4MI&feature=player_embedded) is done when removing a fragments framelayout container so when the container is set to GONE, it just doesnt disapere but instead animates? ie. slide left  Thnx!

Answer (score 1):

1. Implement the [`Animation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/package-summary.html) you want.
2. Create a [`LayoutAnimationController`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/LayoutAnimationController.html) using the animation created in Step 1.
3. [Set the `LayoutAnimation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#setLayoutAnimation%28android.view.animation.LayoutAnimationController%29) of your `ViewGroup` to the `LayoutAnimationController` created in Step 2.
4. Implement an [`Animation.AnimationListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) and set the `FrameLayout`'s visibility to `GONE` in the `onAnimationEnd` method.
5. [Set the LayoutAnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#setLayoutAnimationListener%28android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener%29) to Listener implemented in Step 4.
6. Start the Animation by [`startLayoutAnimation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#startLayoutAnimation%28%29)